# False Negatives (FN) on weka prediction output

Tags: machine-learning, svm, weka

I am working on weka GUI for classification. The following is a small version of the prediction output of an `SVM` classifier. Could any one help me out why it is showing ONLY the `False Positives (FP)`? As you can see, all have a `+` sign in some of the instances. Is there any way to show the False Negatives (FP) as well so that we have some `-` signs?

```
inst#     actual  predicted error prediction
        1   1:normal   1:normal       1
        2   1:normal   1:normal       1
        3  2:anomaly   1:normal   +   1
        4  2:anomaly  2:anomaly       1
        5   1:normal   1:normal       1
        6  2:anomaly   1:normal   +   1
        7  2:anomaly  2:anomaly       1
        8   1:normal   1:normal       1
        9  2:anomaly  2:anomaly       1
       10  2:anomaly   1:normal   +   1
       11  2:anomaly  2:anomaly       1
       12  2:anomaly  2:anomaly       1
       13  2:anomaly   1:normal   +   1
       14  2:anomaly  2:anomaly       1
       15   1:normal  2:anomaly   +   1
       16   1:normal   1:normal       1
       17  2:anomaly   1:normal   +   1
       18   1:normal   1:normal       1
```

A summary

=== Detailed Accuracy By Class ===

```
             TP Rate  FP Rate  Precision  Recall   F-Measure  MCC      ROC Area  PRC Area  Class
             0.936    0.134    0.890      0.936    0.912      0.807    0.967     0.964     normal
             0.866    0.064    0.922      0.866    0.893      0.807    0.965     0.949     anomaly
```

Weighted Avg.    0.904    0.101    0.905      0.904    0.904      0.807    0.966     0.957

```
=== Confusion Matrix ===

     a     b   <-- classified as
 63060  4283 |     a = normal
  7832 50798 |     b = anomaly
```

Comment: @sean-owen, any ideas dear?

Comment: @Prune, how about this one dear?

Answer (score 0):

The False Negatives are included in the output

```
        TP Rate  FP Rate  Precision  Recall   F-Measure  MCC      ROC Area  PRC Area  Class
         0.936    0.134    0.890      0.936    0.912      0.807    0.967     0.964     normal
         0.866    0.064    0.922      0.866    0.893      0.807    0.965     0.949     anomaly
```

The False Positives of class anomally are the False negatives of class normal.

This is as positive/negative is not defined. If you define anomaly as positive then

```
TP: 0.936 / FP 0.134 / FN 0.064 / TN 0.866
```

However, if you define normal as positive

```
TN: 0.936 / FN 0.134 / FP 0.064 / TP 0.866
```

Comment: But I don't see any instance line with a `-` sign in the prediction error. If it shows `+` sign for `False Positives`, shouldn't it show `-` sign for `False Negatives`? I am just confused.

Comment: As I see it from your output,  basically all miss classifications are marked with a +. As positive/negative is not well define, as outlined above, the separation is hardly possible. To understand why pos neg is not well defined you should look into multi class problems.

Comment: I am using weka GUI, where do you check that dear?